# How to put my ads without zoom?

Tags: android, zooming, admob

**Hi, i have a little problem.. I have a WebView and i put FAR zoom, but my ads too was zoomed.
My question is.. How can i do to put my ads correctly ? (Without zoom)
Obviously i want this zoom for my webview
Here my code:**

```
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

import lol.king.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class QuintaActivity extends Activity
{
private WebView browser;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    final AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

            //habilitamos javascript y el zoom
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

//ZOOM
    browser.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);

            browser.loadUrl("http://www.lolking.net/champions/");

    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
                    // evita que los enlaces se abran fuera nuestra app en el navegador de android
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            return false;
        }   

    });
}   

}
```

**And.. here my layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
android:background="@drawable/fondo"
 tools:context=".QuintaActivity" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="0dp" />

<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adUnitId="a152915638b0b40"   
    ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Thanks and sorry for my english :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like setting the default zoom on a WebView is impacting all WebViews.

WebSettings#setDeaultZoom was deprecated in API#19
See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDefaultZoom(android.webkit.WebSettings.ZoomDensity)

I suggest that you follow the alternate mechanisms described in the Javadoc. Not only will this future proof your app it will hopefully allow you to apply zoom to just webView1.

Comment: But.. you don´t understand. I want zoom in WEBVIEW, but NO in the ADS D:
I want ads in "default" zoom but WebView in "FAR" zoom

Comment: I *do* understand. Which is why I suggested using something other than WebSetting#setDefaultZoom as this impacts ALL WebViews.

Comment: Oh, ok thanks, sorry, i don´t have excellent english and i get confused sometimes :D